# In the usual notation, let  + 2 and  − 3 be the position vectors of two points  and , respectively,

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

In the usual notation, let $ + 2$ and $ − 3$ be the position vectors of two points  and , respectively, with respect to a fixed origin . Find the position vectors of the two distinct points C and D such that:

$\widehat{} = \widehat{}= /2$ and $ =  = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Isn't C and D same? how do they differ at all?

Answer (score 0):

Given, $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{OA} \ =\ i\ +\ 2j,\ \overrightarrow{OB} =i\ -\ 3j\ \ $
Let $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{OC} \ =\ ai\ +\ bj$

Since it is given $\displaystyle \angle BOC=\ π/2 \ =\ \angle BOD$
Hence $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{OB\ } .\overrightarrow{OC} \ =\ 0\ $and $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{OB\ } .\overrightarrow{OD} \ =\ 0\ $

Here, C and D are same points.

$\displaystyle a-3b\ =\ 0\ \Longrightarrow \ a\ =\ 3b$
$\displaystyle |AB|\ =\ 5$
$\displaystyle \Longrightarrow |OC|=|OD|\ =\frac{5}{3}$
$\displaystyle a^{2} \ +\ b^{2} \ =\ \frac{25}{9}$
$\displaystyle \Longrightarrow \ 10b^{2} \ =\ 25/9$
Therefore, $\displaystyle a\ =\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\displaystyle b\ =\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3\sqrt{2}}$